# Can I replace AppDynamics with Azure App Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, appdynamics

Our existing Infra is hosted on private servers. [AppDynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/) is used for monitoring hundreds of application & host performances.

As a move we are moving all our applications on Azure. **Is this possible to get away from AppDynamics & use any Azure solutions** for the same purpose. Possibly Azure App Insight/Monitor ??

We have tried Java Application Monitoring on [Azure App Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview); Azure Monitor is useful there. Also we have used LogAnalytics for creating various performance Dashboards on Azure Monitor.

Can Application Insight support all the similar features of AppDynamics: Like Workflow Monitoring Performance Monitoring etc etc..

Comment: I have already seen AppDynamics Capability to monitor Azure Applications as well, but I want to decommission AppDynamics.

Comment: Is it a web project?

Comment: we have mostly REST Services and also Nodejs applications are there.

Comment: I hope Serverless360 can be of help in this case. It helps you to do workflow monitoring (using BAM), Performance monitoring and real-time Metrics monitoring as well. Give it a shout there.